# Escaping values in Mysqljs

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction

**mysqljs** is pretty inconsistent with escaping values, or I am not understanding the docs.

**Error:**

```
this.table = 'elections';
mysql.query('SELECT * FROM ? where name = ?', [this.table, this.votesTable]
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax error:
>   'SELECT * FROM \'elections\' where name = \'prim1000\''

**But this works:**

```
`mysql.query('UPDATE elections SET updated_at = ? WHERE name = ?', [this.getTimeStamp(), this.votesTable])
```

But if I remove "elections" in the query above and put "?" instead it will throw an error. So the following won't work.

```
mysql.query('UPDATE ? SET updated_at = ? WHERE name = ?', [this.table, this.getTimeStamp(), this.votesTable])
```

Comment: What is the question? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the documentation page you linked to, under the section "**Escaping query identifiers**", you should be able to do this:

```
mysql.query('SELECT * FROM ?? where name = ?', [this.table, this.votesTable]
```

Most SQL frameworks do not allow parameters to be used for anything besides individual *values*. I.e. not table identifies, column identifiers, lists of values, or SQL keywords. The mysqljs library is uncommon in that it has support for quoting identifiers and key/value pairs.

---

Re your comment:

The `??` placeholder is for identifiers. Identifiers must be quoted differently from values. In MySQL, a string value is quoted like `'string'` but an identifier is quoted with back-ticks.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` where name = 'myname'
```

The mysqljs class uses the `??` as a special placeholder for an identifier, so you can tell the class it must be quoted with back-ticks.

Comment: This works but I am not sure what's the difference between `??` and `?`.